# IntelliJ: Possible for split editor windows to gain different color scheme?

Tags: intellij-idea

It's about IntelliJ's option "Right Click -> Split Horizontally/Vertically".

Is it possible that the split editor window gets a different color scheme (or a background, at least) than the "original" editor? Just for the sake of easier comparing of the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, colors & fonts settings affect all the editor windows, you known where to file a feature request =)

Comment: Hahaha yes I do know :))). Thanks

Comment: In order not to open another topic in vain, could you help me here. Is Colors&Fonts scheming supported in Community edition? If yes, I will open another topic because I copied XML files into ~/.IntelliJIDEA70/config/colors/ and the IDE 10.0 doesn't see them in [Main Menu] -> [File] -> [Settings] -> [Colors & Fonts] dialog (all I have is default option).

Comment: You are using the wrong folder, refer to http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 .

Comment: Sorry, the correct folder I use is ~/.IntelliJIdea10/config/colors (Linux) and IntelliJ is Community edition 10.0.2. Still no scheme XML file is detected. :(

Comment: Should work fine, contact support for help with more details.